# Add label under button in a flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, button, label, flowlayoutpanel

I need to dynamically create buttons with labels under them in a flowLayoutPanel when i drop a file onto the form. But how do I set the label position to be under the button since the FLP is arranging the controls by itself.. ?

What I've tried:

```
 void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileList = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

        foreach (string s in fileList)
            {
                Button button = new Button();

                button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
                fl_panel.Controls.Add(button);

                Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
                Bitmap bmp = icon.ToBitmap();
                button.BackgroundImage = bmp;
                button.Width = 60;
                button.Height = 75;
                button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;            

                int space = 5;
                int Yy = button.Location.Y;
                int Xx = button.Location.X;
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Location = new Point(Yy + space, Xx);
            //label.Margin.Top = button.Margin.Bottom;

            fl_panel.Controls.Add(label);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea I know of is to implement a custom control that contains both a button and a label that are arranged correctly.  Then add the custom control to the FlowLayoutPanel.

```
public class CustomControl:Control
{
    private Button _button;
    private Label _label;
    public CustomControl(Button button, Label label)
    {
        _button = button;
        _label = label;
        Height = button.Height + label.Height;
        Width = Math.Max(button.Width, label.Width);
        Controls.Add(_button);
        _button.Location = new Point(0,0);
        Controls.Add(_label);
        _label.Location = new Point(0, button.Height);
    }
}
```

You can then add to it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CustomControl c = new CustomControl(new Button {Text = "Button!"}, new Label {Text = "Label!"});
    fl_panel.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to listen to button events, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var button = new Button {Text = "Button " + i};
    CustomControl c = new CustomControl(button, new Label {Text = "Label!"});
    button.Click += buttonClicked;
    fl_panel.Controls.Add(c);
}
...
private void buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button) sender).Text);
}
```

Comment: The control is added nice now, but the click event doesn't fire... before I was using the button.tag and in the click event I was adding the tag to a string  "String path_app = ((sender as CustomControl).Tag as String);"   I used "button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);"  to define the event.. What might be the problem?

Comment: The sender will be a button, not a CustomControl.  Either have the CustomControl listen for a click and then pass it on with the appropriate tag through your own event, or cast the click to a button (sender as Button) and use that.

Comment: Even with the sender as Button is the same thing..
What I have: "CustomControl button = new CustomControl(new Button { Tag = path_app, BackgroundImage = bmp }, new Label { Text = file_name });"

fl_panel.Controls.Add(button);

button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

and in the event click:
String path_app = ((sender as Button).Tag as String);

Comment: I edited the code in my answer to give you a clearer example.